# Circular import: Confusion between package and module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, circular-dependency

Here is my package called neuropredict (bunch of modules and an init file; one of the modules is also called neuropredict):

```
$ 09:50:24 miner neuropredict >>  tree setup.py neuropredict
setup.py [error opening dir]
neuropredict
├── config_neuropredict.py
├── freesurfer.py
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── model_comparison.py
├── neuropredict.py
├── rhst.py
├── test_rhst.py
├── visualize.py

0 directories, 16 files
```

The repo is available at https://github.com/raamana/neuropredict, and the init file for the package (whose folder contents shown above) is:

```
$ 09:50:27 miner neuropredict >>  cat neuropredict/__init__.py 

__all__ = ['neuropredict', 'rhst', 'visualize', 'freesurfer',
           'config_neuropredict', 'model_comparison']

from sys import version_info

if version_info.major==2 and version_info.minor==7:
    import neuropredict, config_neuropredict, rhst, visualize, freesurfer, model_comparison
elif version_info.major > 2:
    from neuropredict import neuropredict, config_neuropredict, rhst, visualize, freesurfer, model_comparison
else:
    raise NotImplementedError('neuropredict supports only 2.7 or Python 3+. Upgrade to Python 3+ is recommended.')
```

The import code in rhst.py (first 20 lines) look like this:

```
$ 09:50:40 miner neuropredict >>  head -n 20 neuropredict/rhst.py
from __future__ import print_function

__all__ = ['run', 'load_results', 'save_results']

if version_info.major==2 and version_info.minor==7:
    import config_neuropredict as cfg
elif version_info.major > 2:
    from neuropredict import config_neuropredict as cfg
else:
    raise NotImplementedError('neuropredict supports only 2.7 or Python 3+. Upgrade to Python 3+ is recommended.')
```

The config file which all the modules in the package need to import contains a bunch of variables (without any `if __name__ == __main__ code`)

```
$ 09:51:22 miner neuropredict >>  head -n 20 neuropredict/config_neuropredict.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
NUM_TREES = 100
COMMON_FIG_SIZE = [9, 9]
CMAP_DATASETS = 'Paired'
```

For the Python 2.7, the following test scripts works (only importing part of the code shown). However, when I run this under Python 3.6, everything breaks (some sort of circular import dance).

```
$ 09:51:52 miner neuropredict >>  head -n 20 neuropredict/test_rhst.py 

import numpy as np
import os
import sys
from sys import version_info
from os.path import join as pjoin, exists as pexists, realpath

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

from pyradigm import MLDataset

if version_info.major==2 and version_info.minor==7:
    from neuropredict import rhst
elif version_info.major > 2:
    from neuropredict.neuropredict import rhst
else:
    raise NotImplementedError('neuropredict supports only 2.7 or Python 3+. Upgrade to Python 3+ is recommended.')
```

From the shown errors, I suspect the confusion is between neuropredict (the package) and neuropredict (the module), which should not occur in Python 3+, given it strongly recommends explicit imports only.

Also, test_rhst.py doesn't report any error when run under pytest, but only when I run it using `python3.6 test_rhst.py` on the terminal.

The error messages have not been very helpful (typically `can not import name rhst` or `can not import name config_neuropredict` ) and not telling me why, such as ModuleNotFoundError.

At this point, I am thinking either to rename the module to something different from the package name neuropredict e.g. neupredict, or squash all the code related to python 2.7, and work exclusively in Python 3+ (which I am not sure will work).

Answer (score 1):

As there's no minimal working example I can't properly test, but if I understand your setup correctly I think the problem is that your `test_rhst.py` is in your `neuropredict/` folder;

When `test_rhst.py` ask Python to load `neuropredict`, Python will look in `test_rhst.py`'s directory and find your `neuropredict.py` file - it will not find the containing directory.

So if you want to import `rhst.py` you should just `import rhst`... Except you probably want to test your package works the way the end users use it (you want `from neuropredict import rhst`). And to do that you should place your test file outside your package.

**Why does `from neuropredict import rhst` work?**
Because `neuropredict.py` itself does `import rhst`. So `from neuropredict import rhst` import `rhst.py` via `neuropredict.py`, not via the `neuropredict/` package/directory.